# Passing to void** instead void* makes the compiler complain about types, why?

Tags: c, void-pointers

I don't understand why the compiler warn me about passing an incompatible pointer type in this code: (in this context what are the difference between `void *` and `void **`) (I don't know if this make some difference but I am using `gnu99` C version)

```
void someFunc(void ** foo) {
    printf("%s\n", *foo);
}

int main() {

    char * text = "some text";
    someFunc(&text);

    return 0;
}
```

and in this not

```
void someFunc(void * foo) { 
    printf("%s\n", foo);
}

int main() {

    char * text = "some text";
    someFunc(text);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`void *` is a type that is implicitly convertible to and from any object pointer type. `void **` isn't - so while you can assign a `char *` to a `void *`, you can ***not*** do the same with `char **` and `void **`.

The reason is that they are **incompatible types:** `char **` points to a `char *`, `void **` points to a `void *`, so their base types don't match.

Comment: ok, understood, so when i have a swap function like
void swap(<type> ** a, <type> ** b) to swap pointer instead the values. If i want make it generic (type insensitive or whatever) what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: @Sasquash Sorry, I don't get what you mean by that. It's enough to have `T *` in order to swap two value of type `T`.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your code in the second example, you can do one of the following:

```
// Solution A, preferred:
void someFunc(char * foo) { 
    printf("%s\n", foo);
}

int main() {

    char * text = "some text";
    someFunc(text);

    return 0;
}
```

In A you are telling the compiler that the parameter being passed is a pointer to a char.
I haven't tried solution B, should work but why use voids if they are NOT absolutely necessary.

```
// Solution B, should work but a purist might object:
void someFunc(void * foo) { 
    printf("%s\n", foo);
}

int main() {

    char * text = "some text";
    someFunc( (void *) text);

    return 0;
}
```

In this question there is no obvious reason to use a double ptr, so Solution A for your second example is probably the way to go.